Query parsing error: unexpected token: 'T15'
I have the following pipeline expression under source of the copy activity (Copying data from Salesforce to Azure SQL DB):
@concat('Select Name, PersonEmail, RecordTypeId, PersonTitle 
from Account 
where LastModifiedDate>',variables('LastModAccount'))

LastModAccount has a value of "2024-02-14T15:02:57Z".
Getting Query parsing error: unexpected token: 'T15'.
Not sure where the query parsing is failing

LastModifiedDate>',variables any reason why you have ', here?

If you try to use the query as text without concat, does it work?
